SPDT Slider Switch Wiring, 1P3T 4 Pins No Common Pin
I am trying to figure out how to wire 4 pins 3 positions SPDT switch. Switch has no common pin and I am trying to connect 3 resistor voltage dividers to switch for giving feedback to buck converter.
There is 4 pins and no common pin. If pins are A, B, C and D then available options are AB, BC and CD. I want to toggle between voltage dividers using this switch.
 


I believe it is a poor dwg and A is the common pole.

i checked with multimeter and there is no common pin. I even checked mounting pins if they are common but no chance.

Find a reputable switch distributor (that's one who provides a data sheet), read the data sheet and understand how the device works.

whait is this for?   are you trying to set/change  the output voltage of a regulator?  which one?

You might want to consider the selection of the switch to another model that fits in a simpler way. However, if you accept that the different relations are not in the order you show them, this is a possible solution.
First let's draw a combined schematic that uses 5 resistors to allow all combinations:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Luckily, the shorting connections match the switch, so this results:

simulate this circuit
You will also need to accept that there is an additional series resistor in position 1 to the feedback. If you cannot live with it, you need to choose  another switch. The resulting resistor network is shown here:

simulate this circuit

Thank you very much, you really gave effort for calculating resistors. Additional series resistors are not problem.  Accepting this answer.


Figure 1. The contact arrangement you've got. C&K L-series 3-position switch (from page 2 of the datasheet).

Figure 2. The contact arrangement you want - an SP3T. C&K AYZ Series
Miniature Slide Switches (from page I-47 of the datasheet).
Note that effectively this switch has five internal contacts with 3 and C being common. Externally it can be identified by the space between pins 3 and 4.

so you have a switch that can A-B  B-C  or C-D and you need voltage a voltage divider for
0.1
0.14
and 0.25

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

i think this will not give same results. Resistor totals become like this with this setup
A-B 20k/2.2k
B-C 20k/3.2k
C-D 10K/3.3k
Which are not same with required values.

@yusufşahin, you probably don't care about actual values. You care about voltage divider ratios. You configurations give 11.54%, 16.13% and 33.00%. Jasen's solution gives you 11.00%, 16.50% and 33.00% with, I think, standard E24 values. Is that close enough? You don't mention precision / accuracy requirements in your question.

just noticed that that the output is called "feedback"  - so I guess this is a voltage divider to set the feedback ratio, and thus the output voltage of a voltage regulator

@Transistor i didnt notice ratios, yes then ratios are close. Sorry for not seeing it.
